# How to get Data from Mysql to be in Value of text in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

How to get Data from Mysql to be in Value of text in servlet

I try this code but it is not working

```
 while(rs.next()){
        out.println("<form action=\"userpage\" method=\"post\">"
                + "    <input type=\"text\" name=\"ID_customer\" value=\"<%=rs.getString(1)%>\">"
                 +  "</form>");
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to create separate *view* (.jsp) instead of producing dynamic content of html in `Servlet`.

First of all create the `List<T>` to represent database result in servlet or model class and assign that `list` object into request (request scope) via `request.setAttribute()` method.

```
public class Customer
{
   private int id;
   .....
   public void setId(int id) { }
   public int getId() { return id;}
}
```

In servlet,

```
List<Customer> listOfCustomer=new ArrayList<Customer>();
//code to populate the listOfCustomer from database

request.setAttribute("list",listOfCustomer);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/show.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

The *view* show.jsp should be:

```
<c:forEach var="customer" items="${listOfCustomer}">
   <form method='post' action='servlet_url'>
        <input type="text" 
               name="ID_customer" 
               value="${customer.id}" />
   </form>
</c:forEach>
```